# Change mouse button to navigate "Back" in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, button-remapping, mouse-buttons

One of my mouse buttons when pressed would always navigate back in Chrome and Windows Explorer etc.

For some reason today this button now stretches the focused window into half the screen.

How can I reassign this button to navigate back?  I can't find any options in Chrome or Windows!

I'm on **Windows 10**, with a **Logitech G700** mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logitech G700 is a gaming mouse with multiple keys. There are seperate drivers and a handling software that comes with gaming mice.

If you got a disk in the package with your mouse, insert it and install the software. OR you can find it on Logitech website, here:
http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-gaming-mouse-g700#download

After installation of the software and driver, you can easily configure all your mouse buttons and re-assign their functions.